# Multi-panel plots with for loops

Tags: r

I want to create multi-layer plots using for-loops. The main dataframe I am working with has the following characteristics:

```
         product: 55_ab_LL_bubbles_D1 | 55_ab_LL_troubles_D1 | 34_ac_LL_bubbles_D1 | 34_ac_LL_troubles_D1
   Color
   Blue       453.3                     766.1                 562.1                  883.3
   Green      775.5                     897.1                 434.5                  983.4
   Purple     883.4                     445.7                 787.2                  555.5
   Yellow     764.1                     445.6                 887.3                  673.5
```

From the code below, I am running loop down the rownames (Color) to create a scatter plot.

What I would like to do is, not only run the current loop down the rownames, but I also want to create individual scatter plots for each product (based on the first string "55_", "34_" etc..). I want to group all data points for the number preceding in the product, create the independent scatter plots for each of these numbers for each of the colors. So instead of the four scatter plots it gives me right now (one for each color), I would like to have 8 (for each color and each product number).
Any suggestion is appreciated :) !

CODE:

```
pdf("scatterplot.pdf")
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))){
    
df <- data.frame(x= data[i, grep("bubbles_", colnames(data))],
               y= data[i, grep("troubles_",colnames(data))])
   
  plot(df$x, df$y,
   xlim=xy, ylim = xy)
    }
dev.off()
```